# CopyTruncate log rotation mechanism is dropping logs

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate, log-rotation

I had implemented a linux based logrotation with copytruncate strategy. Below is the config for same:

```
/data/app/info.log {
missingok
copytruncate
maxsize 50M
daily
rotate 30
create 644 app app
delaycompress
compress
}
```

With above config, whenever logrotation task is triggered with application simultaneously writing logs, some log lines are getting dropped. Can someone please guide what am I doing wrong or suggest any other log rotation strategy with no data loss.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few months old but simply for the benefit of others:  You are not doing anything wrong.  From the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

> **copytruncate:**
> Truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one. It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever. ***Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost***. When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place."